# How to chain the operation in a pipeline when data of second operation is dependent upon first

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a scenario in which some DB calls dependent upon other, hence I am not getting how to chain all these operation.
Scenario: 3 tables are considered. One for getting incremental number from a table (DB call 1), then after getting the number, increment & save it (DB call 2), then using it to store it in another table (DB call 3), then need to store some more information in a child table of previous operation's table (DB call 4)

I am not able to get how to keep all these operation in one pipeline. Hence, I did nested operation. Due to which before completion of all DB operation, API is returning the value already. So, in worst case scenario, if 4th DB call operation is failing, still the API has returned the value which shouldn't happen.
Can anyone suggest how to make this task in one chain?
How to pass first DB call's operation to other operation in same chain?

```
public Mono<MasterResponse> createMasterDetails(MasterRequest request)
{
    MasterResponse response = new MasterResponse(); 
    
    // DB op 1
    seriesRepo.findByItemType(request.getItemType())
    .doOnSuccess( series -> {
        if(series == null)
          throw new RunTimeException("Series detail not found for itemType: " + request.getItemType());

        // 2nd DB operation is within this method
        String billNo = getBillNumberByType(series);
        
        MasterDetails masterDetails = new MasterDetails();
        // operation to copy request info to masterDetails
        masterDetails.setBillNo(billNo);
        
        // returning dto value set
        response.setBillNo(billNo);
         
        // DB op 3
        masterDetailsRepo.save(masterDetails)       
        .doOnSuccess(masterData -> {
            
            MasterAttribute masterAttribute = new MasterAttribute();
            // operation to copy request info to masterAttribute
            masterDetails.setMasterId(masterData.getId());
            
            masterDetailsRepo.save(masterDetails)
              .doOnSuccess(ardRes -> log.info("master details saved in DB."))
              .subscribe();             
        
        }).subscribe();
    }).doOnError(err ->{
      log.error("Unable to fetch information from series :: {}", err.getMessage()); 
      Mono.error(new RunTimeException("Unable to fetch information from series :: {}" + err.getMessage()));
      }).block();        

    return Mono.just(response);
}
```

Comment: Stop using  `doOnSuccess` that is used for side-effects. If you don’t know what a side effect is, then look it up. Logging is for instance a side effect. You should be using `flatMap` Instead and also remove all subscribe calls and never call `block` in a reactice application.

Comment: @Toerktumlare so I need to replace doOnSuccess method with flatMap method. That much is sufficient? like from perspective of API returning value before doing all DB call & transaction handling if I do in future?

Comment: I suggest you go through the getting started section of the spring reactor documentation. Developing with reactor is a whole new way of thinking when it comes to programming, and tbh its not just ”switching to flatMap” will solve everything. Stack overflow is not the place to ask if you want to learn the basics, i suggest you do a bit more research on how reactor works. Because as i said in my first comment, its also about not subscribing and not blocking.

Comment: The getting started section will answer your question of how to pass values through the reactive pipeline, so please put some effort before asking here. Please read this and the first answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding you could actually make it more succint and also you dont need to use block().
Here's a sample code which you could use

```
 return seriesRepo
  .findByItemType(request.getItemType())
  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error({YOUR EXCEPTION})))
  .flatMap(series -> Mono.just( getBillNumberByType(series) ))
  .flatMap(billNo -> {
     MasterDetails masterDetails = new MasterDetails();
     // operation to copy request info to masterDetails
     masterDetails.setBillNo(billNo);
     return Mono.just(masterDetails);
  }).flatMap(masterDetailsRepo::save)
  .flatMap( masterDetails -> {
      MasterResponse response = new MasterResponse(); 
      response.setBillNo(masterDetails.getBillNo())
      return Mono.just(response);
  })
```

Comment: There is no need to use flatmap in the `getBillNumberByType` part, map could be used there since its not a reactive method.
Same for  `MasterDetails` and `MasterResponse`

Comment: i completely agree. Since its not using reactive db api, the map would work. thanks

Comment: thanks for the code & help. It solve my problem. But, I have one doubt, API is returning the data of response which was set at the time of bill number generate (getBillNumberByType method). And, below save methods related data are not there in DB. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doubt: for saveAll() of repo, how to pass it to next flatMap? 

Also, one more question if we just write repo.save() & return something else instead of return repo.save() will not call save?

Comment: Regarding the first question..i am not sure of your exact logic so not sure if i will be able to help there.  But if there is a value which you want to propagate down and send that as response..i suggest you wrap that value in tuple and send it down the chain.

Comment: what does saveAll() return ?? If it returns a list or single element  then definitely you return the response of saveAll() to the chain by either doing Flux.just(values) or Mono.just(value) . I don't see any issue.  I would also encourage you to put little bit of more effort and research.Here's some links which you can go through -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0Un1HNdB4jFCsHsQg2HOfO03XfECuMiw ( no affiliation just trying to help).

Comment: @Harry, I got it. I have called save() of repo, but never returned it. Once I returning the value of save() to next flatMap it worked.  Regarding my 1st query getBilNumberType, I divided into logic part into map() & db call to flatMap() all good. for saveAll() it don't allow to return to flatMap() directly, so added saveAll(xyz).collectList().
Thanks for the help